# Highchart line renders bigger when exported to pdf using css2pdf

Tags: highcharts, render, export-to-pdf

I have a problem when i export my Highchart chart to pdf using css2pdf. Chart line gets bigger in pdf always, it doesnt mater if i set chart line width.

Here is the image of chart in html:
[html chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UNMs.png)

Here is the code for my chart:

```
Highcharts.chart('centersChartcontainer', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Centers'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Centers by year'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: $scope.yearsECMOArray,

            labels: {
                interval: 1,
                rotation: 0,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '6px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',

                }
                , y: 8

            }
        },
        {
            categories: $scope.countsECMOArray,
            linkedTo: 0,
            labels: {
                rotation: 0,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '6px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
                , y: 8
            }

            , opposite: false
        },
        {
            categories: $scope.casesECMOArray,
            linkedTo: 0,
            labels: {
                rotation: 0,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '6px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
                , y: 8
            }

            , opposite: false
        },

        {
            categories: $scope.casesECMOArray,
            linkedTo: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }

        ],
        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                    fontSize: '6px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            },
            title: {

                text: 'Cases',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                }
            },
            opposite: true

        }, {
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                    fontSize: '6px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                    borderWidth: '3px'
                }
                ,borderWidth:4
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Counts',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }

        }],
        plotOptions: {//This disables dots on spline
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                },
               enableMouseTracking: false                  
            },
            series: {
                animation: false
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            y: -4.5,
            floating: true,
            itemStyle: {
                fontSize: '6px',
                font: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                color: '#A0A0A0',

            },

        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Counts',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: $scope.countsECMOArray,
            color: '#9a0000'

        }, {
            name: 'Cases',
            type: 'spline',
            yAxis: 0,
            data: $scope.casesECMOArray,

            color: '#428bca',
            lineWidth: 0.5
        }]
    });
```

Here is the html side code related to chart and export link:

```
<div id="pdfContentHolder" style="margin:auto; width: 720px; height: 800px;"><div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="blackHeaderHolder">Centers</div>          
<div id="centersChartcontainer" style="min-width: 400px; height: 500px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div></div><a href="#" onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('pdfContentHolder',{render:'download'},{pageWidth:'216mm', pageHeight:'279mm'});">Export to Pdf</a>
```

If you take a look at last lines of chart i used lineWidth: 0.5 for line and it works on chart while in html. But in pdf line is still same size, big. If i increase this width it will also increase width in pdf too and it will be much bigger, also if i put 0 it will be presented as big line but transparent.

### I updated chart code. It works now. If someone else has this problem in future like i did. Just add this property 'enableMouseTracking: false' and it will work.

[shieldChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZonQZ.png)

Comment: Could you disable tooltip for testing? It looks like a tracker for tooltip.

Comment: When you said that i thought it will work, but i disabled it and it still stays the same, line is wide in pdf.

Comment: What it you set this as 1px? Will that work? Maybe css2pdf considers 0.5 as 5? Any chance to setup live demo with issue?

Comment: I just tried that, but it just increases size in html. Not having effect in pdf. Look my question update, i found out that high chart is bugging.

Comment: I'm not sure how is shield UI connected to the issue. Maybe you have an old version of Highcharts? Anyway, could you please create a live demo? Thanks.

Comment: I just compared shield with highcharts.
Im using linked library from highcharts website.
il try to create live demo, and send you link when that is done.

Comment: Pawel you solved my problem with that tracker option on github. I am grateful, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a strange one.

I would try adding the `lineWidth` setting in the `exporting` object as well.

Example:

```
exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                lineWidth: 0.5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions

Comment: I tried this, its not working. This is for exporting using highchart export. But im exporting this to pdf using css2pdf formater.
Im exporting with this:
<a href="#" onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('pdfContentHolder',{render:'download'},{pageWidth:'216mm', pageHeight:'279mm'});">Export to Pdf</a>

Comment: Ah. I see. How about setting a custom CSS rule for the line?

Comment: Tried but not working.
Look my question update, i found out that high chart is bugging.