# Line not show properly while exporting HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: highcharts, wkhtmltopdf

We are using HighCharts to show Data on UI.
While Exporting all HTML pages into PDF Scatter graph line get disturb.
For Exporting HTML to PDF we are using wkhtmltopdf.

Please find attachment.

[Before exporting HTML page to PDF image looks like Shown in Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0KjZ.png)

[After exporting HTML page to PDF scatter line shown in Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE0Wx.png)

Comment: Have you tried using **highcharts exporting module** instead of wkhtmltopdf?: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: Thank you for your valuable Answer but Export option only export graph not whole page and while PDF generate I need the whole page as a image, that why I am using wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wkhtmltopdf fails to printing SVG path (highchart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160340/wkhtmltopdf-fails-to-printing-svg-path-highchart)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is related to this topic

[Highchart line renders bigger when exported to pdf using css2pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804214/highchart-line-renders-bigger-when-exported-to-pdf-using-css2pdf)

I also encountered that issue using mpdf60 so this is how i fixed it.

If your using Highcharts.getSVG change the enableMouseTracking to false

```
var chart =  $(your chart id).highcharts();
chart.options.plotOptions.line.enableMouseTracking = false;
```

or you can set it directly on your chart

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal', 
            enableMouseTracking: false
        },
        line: {
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
},
```